# ¿Se puede imprimir una raiz con todo y signo en una terminal de Python?

Tags: python, xcode

Tengo una consulta, hay alguna forma de poder imprimir en la consola de python una raiz?

O sea es que a la hora de que, imprimo el resultado de una ecuacion en donde el resultado es una raiz, lo que hace python es devolverme el valor pero en decimal, pero lo que yo quiero en ver la raiz.

gracias!!

Esto es lo que me devuelve

[image: Esto es lo que me devuelve]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca falta un ejemplo claro de lo que te pasa y lo que queres que pase....

Comment: Lee los enlaces que te dio gbianchi!

Comment: Esta mal formulada la pregunta?

Comment: Sí, está incompleta tu pregunta. No sabemos qué código genera esa salida. Lee los enlaces que te comparten, añade el código que quieres arreglar y ya habrá algo que nosotros podamos ayudar a revisar

Comment: Estás usando Xcode para compilar python y por eso agregaste la etiqueta?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mostrar el símbolo utilizando el unicode `'\u221A'`. De esta manera si quieres mostrar la raíz cuadrada de algún valor solo pondrías este código antes de tu resultado.

```
print('\u221A',math.sqrt(25))
```

Dando como resultado

```
√ 5.0
```

Si quieres personalizar el resultado ya depende de como utilices el código.

Comment: Excelente Muchas Gracias!!